Weston black screen issue after Chromium launches
We are facing black screen issue while running web browsers such as Chromium/Qt quicknanobrowser with weston. Here is the detail:
The board is based on i.mx8m mini Soc and Linux 6.1.22. After board bootup, the weston service works fine. The wayland clients such as weston-flower/weston-terminal can show their windows on the screen as expected.
But after launching browsers such as Chromium, the screen suddenly becomes black. The weston process is still running. After restart weston service, the screen display resumes normally.
One interesting finding is, while the screen is black, I run weston-screenshooter command on the console to do screen capture, the captured image looks fine. I can see the browser' window indeed from the image. Why is it not shown on screen?
